# What is the quickest and easiest way to use date picker in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am a beginner in AngularJS and trying to use date picker. I tried to use plain jquery UI based date picker. But it isn't working as expected. So will someone help me with some code that is the easiest way to achieve angular js? I have tried using 720kb angular date picker, I have followed the instructions and nothing happens no error nothing!

app.js:

```
// Included in dependency injection.  
let app = angular.module('mainApp', [ 
    '720kb.datepicker', 'ngRoute', 'fetchModule' ]);
```

main.html Page:

```
// Added stylesheet
<!-- Angular Datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-datepicker/2.1.17/angular-datepicker.min.css">
// and the js file at the end of the main page.
<!-- Angular Date Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-datepicker/2.1.17/angular-datepicker.min.js">
</script>
```

Template:

```
// This is in the template that loads into view 
<datepicker>
  <input ng-model="date" type="text"/>
</datepicker>
```

Finally checking the order of all .js's in main.html:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular -->
<script src="/app/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular Date Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-datepicker/2.1.17/angular-datepicker.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Angular Router -->
<script src="/app/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular App -->
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
<!-- Fetch Module -->
<script src="/app/fetch/fetchModule.js"></script>
<script src="/app/fetch/controllers.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use datepicker from [angular-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker) which is written by the angular-ui team and you don't need jQuery for that and it's all Angular.

(Try not to use jQuery if possible because both Angular & jQuery are heavy library and there are almost everything available for Angular that is available for jQuery, for example: datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myDate = angular.module('myDate', []);

myDate.directive("datepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var updateModel = function (dateText) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
        });
      };
      var options = {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
          updateModel(dateText);
        }
      };
      elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"> </script>      
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="main_continer" ng-app="myDate">
  <input type="text" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker />
</div>
```